# DVD-RAM - size mismatch for same brand

Tags: windows-7, backup, dvd

I'm still using DVD-RAM disks for archiving purposes, and during a move, a few disks of one archive-set were damaged, so I needed to create copies from the good set, and that's when things got bad:

All disks are Verbatim 5x DVD-RAM ones, bought as a single batch of 100, and all of them came labeled "UDF_MEI" and preformatted with the UDF 2.01 file system, and all show up as having 4.27 GB free space, in the Windows 7 Properties:

Used Space: 284,672 bytes

Free Space: 4,579,371,008 bytes

However, when copying one particular backup to a fresh disk, it failed, as this one disk shows, even after formatting (after copying it's contents to two external disks):

Used Space: 292,864 bytes

Free Space: 4,698,900,480 bytes

which actually adds up to 4,699,193,344 bytes, which is the advertised space of 4.7Gb. What's more, comparing the contents of this disk with an older backup spread over a set of CD-ROMs showed that the contents are exactly the same.

Can anyone give me an explanation for this size mismatch? Can it be the fact that the "big" one was created on XP, and the small one on W7? Can the drive cause it? I am clueless, totally clueless.

Comment: I am not sure for certain but probably because of different block sizes.

Comment: No, they are the same, 2,048 bytes, and as I mentioned, the "big" disk stays big, even after a reformat.